# insert comma after the last letter

Tags: text-processing, csv

I use a txt file, and I need to convert it in csv file

```
Saint Petersburg      0     10    0.1   -   N
Moscow                -     9       0   -   N
Novgorod              0     7       1   30  Y
```

In bash, how can I insert comma after the last letter, and after every number or "-"

For example

```
Saint Petersburg,      0,     10,    0.1,   -,  N
Moscow,                -,     9,       0,   -,  N
Novgorod,              0,     7,       1,   30, Y
```

Best

Comment: Must this be done with `bash` alone? Are the fields separated by tabs?

Comment: it is not a problem with another language, but I prefer not to mix codes...but it is not a problem. The number fields are separated by tabs, well I think. The cities field and the second field with several tabs...I think...

Comment: @EnricAgudPique when asking such questions, the nature of the field delimiter is essential. Most solutions will depend on it. You can find out by passing your file through `od` : `od -c file.csv`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will replace sequences of 2 or more spaces by a command and the same spaces less one:

```
sed 's/ \( \+\)/,\1/g' file.txt
```

It will fail if there is only one space between columns.

---

If you only want `", "` as the field separator:

```
sed 's/ \{2,\}/, /g' file
```

Comment: It is great!!! Now I want to delete spaces between fields, and I use sed -r 's/\s+/ /g' ...it runs...is it possible to use both commands in a simple line?